# Trouble reading a file in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a file but for some reason it is not working and I have some trouble to diagnose the problem as I'm not used to python.

I use the following code to read the file

```
with open(self.lineEdit_2.text(), 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    idList = []
    idExist = false
    for row in reader:
        print(row[1])
        for i in len(idList):
            if row[1] == idList[i]:
                idExist = true
                break
            else:
                idExist = false
    if not idExist:
        idList.append(row[1])
```

The file is called can_data.txt and `self.lineEdit_2.text()` return the destination to that file. The file has the following structure:

```
1542208616,0x7DF,8,01 03 55 55 55 55 55 55 
1542208616,0x7E9,8,02 43 00 00 00 00 00 00 
1542208616,0x7E8,8,02 43 00 00 00 00 00 00 
1542208616,0x7DF,8,01 07 55 55 55 55 55 55 
1542208616,0x7E9,8,02 47 00 00 00 00 00 00 
1542208616,0x7E8,8,02 47 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

The purpose is to list the different ids that is inside the file in column 1.

While trying to debug it exit when it reach for `row in reader:`

Comment: What exactly is your intention with this code?

Comment: I think the last two lines should be indented to be inside the main for loop.

Comment: How do you know it is not working? (Do not reply to this comment; it is a suggestion to [edit] your post.)

Comment: The inner for loop can be avoided by using a containment test (e.g. `if row[1] in idList`). Also, `True` and `False` must be capitalized in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a constraint on which package you use to read your files?
If not, why not try pandas?

From what I understand from your script, the second column contains ids, and you what a list of all different ids that appear in your data.

You can therefore try this (my guess is that it will be faaar more efficient):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table(self.lineEdit_2.text() , sep=',', names=['c0', 'id', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6'])
unique_ids = df['id'].unique()
```

Comment: This one is really awesome and easy to use! Thanks for a nice suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all: fix your indentation! After `with ...:` there should always be an indented block.

Secondly what does self.lineEdit_2.text() return? The `open()` method expects the path of the file as it's first argument, not the text you're trying to read... (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

My guess is that you don't need the first line at all but something like this might work:

```
reader = csv.reader(self.lineEdit_2.text().split('\n'), delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    ...
```